# Generate yaml node anchors and references programmatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I need to generate this yaml programmatically in Rails:

```
foo: &foo
  x: 1
  y: 2

bar:
  <<: *foo
  z: 3
```

which when it's parsed should give this hash:

```
output = {
    :foo => {
        :x => 1,
        :y => 2
    },
    :bar => {
        :x => 1,
        :y => 2,
        :z => 3
    }
}
```

Obviously `output.to_yaml` gives the expanded syntax. Is there any way to output the yml syntax with [anchor and nodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#References) programmatically.

Comment: [this might be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665897/read-and-write-yaml-files-without-destroying-anchors-and-aliases)

Comment: what is your expected output? May I know ?

Comment: @OMG the yaml snipped posted at the beginning of the question.

Comment: why you are not looking [`YAML`](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/YAML.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar feature where i read from an initializer many YAML files and appended to a global variable. it is something like this:

```
APP = Hash.new
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/config/data/*.yml").each do |file|
  fdata = File.open(file).read
  APP.merge!(YAML::load(ERB.new(fdata).result(binding)).symbolize_keys!)
end
```

I should know more about your problem to write a more specific solution.

The main point is the YAML::load method, which reads de yaml formated text and outputs a hash.
the ERB is because Yaml files could contain erb tags which should be interpreted. It could or could not be needed. 
symbolize_keys! is for accessing with [:symbols] and not ["strings"] to keys.