# ruby yaml dump: how to prevent alias dereferencing?

Tags: ruby, yaml, alias

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read and write YAML files without destroying anchors and aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665897/read-and-write-yaml-files-without-destroying-anchors-and-aliases)

I am using ruby 1.9.3 with default yaml engine to modify yaml files on the fly within the app like this:

```
require 'yaml'

langs = YAML.load_file("i18n/de.yml")

langs["key"] = 'val' # change key to new value val

File.open("i18n/de.yml", 'w') do |f|
    YAML.dump(langs,f)
end
```

This works very well, but I have a problem with aliases in the yml. So assume `de.yml` is this:

```
---
main: &aliasName
  key:
    title: translation
  another_key:
    title: another translation

something:
  <<: *aliasName
```

After calling the script like above, this get's translated to:

```
---
main:
  key: &18803600
    title: translation
  another_key: &18803120
    title: another translation
something:
  key: *18803600
  another_key: *18803120
key: val
```

If I now add something to `main` by editing the file by hand, for example `main.third_key`, it won't get aliased in `something` since the alias was converted to explicitly only alias `main.key` and `main.another_key` between `main` and `something`.

So it looks like the aliases get dereferenced on `YAML.dump` or `YAML.load`. Is there any way to save the aliases like they are defined in the yaml file? `de.yml` might look like this (I don't care if the alias name changes):

```
---
main: &18803600
  key: 
    title: translation
  another_key:
    title: another translation
something:
  <<: *18803600
key: val
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you editing the file by hand? In an editor?

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583588/read-and-write-yaml-files-without-destroying-anchors-and-aliases