# Annotating Ruby structures to include anchors/references on #to_yaml

Tags: ruby, hash, yaml

I have some large hashes (>10⁵ keys) with interlocking structures.  They're stored on disk as YAML.  I'd like to avoid duplication by using anchors and references in the YAML, but I haven't been able to figure out if there's a way to do it implicitly in the hash such that the `#to_yaml` method will label the anchor nodes properly.

Desired YAML:

```
--- 
parent1:
  common-element-1: &CE1
    complex-structure-goes: here
parent2:
  uncomment-element-1:
    blah: blah
  <<: *CE1
```

Ruby code:

```
hsh = {
  'parent1' => {
    'common-element-1' => {
      'complex-structure-goes' => 'here',
    },
  'parent2' => {
    'uncommon-element-1' => {
      'blah' => 'blah',
    },
    '<<' => '*CE1',
  },
}
```

The reference is quite straightforward -- but how to embed the `&CE1` anchor in the `'common-element-1'` item in the Ruby hash?

I want to work as much as possible with native Ruby primitive types (like `Hash`) rather than mucking about with builders and emitters and such -- and I **definitely** don't want to write the YAML manually!

I've looked at [Read and write YAML files without destroying anchors and aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665897/read-and-write-yaml-files-without-destroying-anchors-and-aliases) and [its relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583588/read-and-write-yaml-files-without-destroying-anchors-and-aliases), among other places, but haven't found an answer yet -- at least not that I've understood.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the same Ruby object, the YAML library will set up references for you:

```
> common = {"ohai" => "I am common"}
> doc = {"parent1" => {"id" => 1, "stuff" => common}, "parent2" => {"id" => 2, "stuff" => common}}
> puts doc.to_yaml
---
parent1:
  id: 1
  stuff: &70133422893680
    ohai: I am common
parent2:
  id: 2
  stuff: *70133422893680
```

I'm not sure there's a straightforward way of defining Hashes that are subsets of each other, though.  Perhaps tweaking your structure a bit would be warranted?

Comment: I did not know that.  That's excessively cool, and I think will suit my purpose.  Thanks!