# Create special characters in yaml through Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, yaml

I'm working on a `gem` and there I need to create a file like `database.yml` . I'm creating Yaml file but something not happening good . Below is my code

**Key value pairs**

```
    STATUS_VALUES =[
                        {   
                            'default' => {
                                            'defaults' =>
                                                {
                                                    'adapter' => 'pasql',
                                                    'encoding'=> 'utf8',
                                                    'database'=> 'mysql',
                                                    'username'=> 'root',
                                                    'password'=> nil
                                                }
                                            }
                        },
                        {
                            'development' => 
                                {
                                    '{{<<}}' => '*default'
                                }
                        }
                    ]


data = STATUS_VALUES
    File.open(file, 'w') { |f| YAML.dump(data.to_yaml, f) }
```

**My Expected output**

```
  - default: &defaults
      adapter: pasql
      encoding: utf8
      database: mysql
      username: root
      password: 
  - development:
      <<: *default
```

**My actual output**

```
 - default:
      adapter: pasql
      encoding: utf8
      database: mysql
      username: root
      password: ''
  - development:
      !!str '<<': "*default"
```

**To be clear I have three differences here**

1. first line i.e default  , i want it to be default: &defaults
2. second password needs to be without any value
3. last line `!!str '<<': "*default"` needed to be `<<: *default`

Any help will be greatly appreciating - Have a good day - thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read and write YAML files without destroying anchors and aliases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583588/read-and-write-yaml-files-without-destroying-anchors-and-aliases)