# ToRubyNoMerge argument error - Psych - Yaml Parser - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml, psych

I'm making dynamic `yaml file` in `Ruby`

I have following hash

```
{
  "defaults"=>
          {"foo"=>"bar", "zip"=>"button"},
           "node"=>
                  {
                   "<<"=>
                  {"foo"=>"bar", "zip"=>"button"}, 
                   "foo"=>"other"
                   }
}
```

when i try to parse it using

```
tree = Psych.parse your_data
data = ToRubyNoMerge.new.accept tree
```

having parser functions override like here

```
require 'psych'
class ToRubyNoMerge < Psych::Visitors::ToRuby
  def revive_hash hash, o
    if o.anchor
      @st[o.anchor] = hash
      hash.instance_variable_set "@_yaml_anchor_name", o.anchor
    end

    o.children.each_slice(2) { |k,v|
      key = accept(k)
      hash[key] = accept(v)
    }
    hash
  end
end

class MyEmitter < Psych::Visitors::Emitter
  def visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping o
    o.anchor = 'defaults' if o.anchor
    super
  end

  def visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias o
    o.anchor = 'defaults' if o.anchor
    super
  end
end
```

Now when i try

```
tree = Psych.dump yaml_constants
data = ToRubyNoMerge.new.accept tree
File.open(file, 'w') { |f| YAML.dump(data.to_yaml, f) }
```

It give me below **error**

> psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:23:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2) (ArgumentError)

we can see that it makes sense , because `revive_hash` is taking two arguments but the same thing worked for [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665897/read-and-write-yaml-files-without-destroying-anchors-and-aliases) guys . can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong

Note: I'm following [This Post for parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665897/read-and-write-yaml-files-without-destroying-anchors-and-aliases) and asked @matt for this issue but he's not responsing

Answer (score 0):

> we can see that it makes sense, because `revive_hash` is taking two arguments

The error you are getting has nothing to do with `revive_hash`.

As one might read in the documentation, [`Psych::Visitors::ToRuby#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych/Visitors/ToRuby.html#method-c-new) expects two params: `ClassLoader` and `ScalarScanner`.

You instantiate `ToRubyMerge`, which is a direct descendant of the above, providing no parameters to `initialize` at all. This is exactly what the error you get is saying.

To use defaults for both one might use [`#create`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych/Visitors/ToRuby.html#method-c-create) factory:

```
#             ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
ToRubyNoMerge.create.accept tree
```

Comment: dear i made the change and now it says - undefined method `visit_String' for #< ToRubyNoMerge .

Comment: This is completely unrelated to the original question.

Comment: i also think so , okay i check for this error and then i'll check for your answer too .. i just thought it worth to ask - thanks again . but if you have any info about it kindly lemme know